# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I have this 3 tables on my database. I am trying to group `bId` which is an FK to the table of `Baptism`. `BSponsors` is a table for Sponsors of Baptism so obviously `bId` column will be repeatedly displayed on my page if I am not going to group it. So I tried the code below but error is popping up saying:

> Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause SQL Server

```
SELECT p.pId, p.Lname, p.Fname, p.Mname, p.BirthDate, p.HomeAddress, 
    p.PlaceOfBirth,     p.Age, p.BirthDate, b.*, s.*,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=b.pId) AS child,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=b.fatherID) AS father,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=b.motherID) AS mother,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=b.guardianID) AS guardian,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=b.revID) AS rev,
(SELECT sp.Fname+' '+sp.Lname FROM Profile sp WHERE sp.pId=s.pId) AS sponsors
FROM Baptism b
INNER JOIN Profile p
ON p.pId=b.pId
INNER JOIN BSponsors s
ON b.bId = s.bId
GROUP BY s.bId
```

Comment: Just remove the `GROUP BY s.bId`?

Answer (score 2):

You got the error

> Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause SQL Server

It means that there is grouped result and some columns are unused in "group by". So you need to add your columns and all columns from tables Baptism and BSponsors to group:

```
GROUP BY p.pId, p.Lname, p.Fname, p.Mname, p.BirthDate, p.HomeAddress, p.PlaceOfBirth, p.Age, p.BirthDate, b.pId, s.pId ...
```

If you remove group by, you'll get a lot of trash in result query (all columns from baptism, sponsors and sub-selects)

Answer (score 1):

This is not how group by works. You can’t group by columnA and then have columnB, columnC, columnD in the select statement.

Here are several good articles that will point you in the right direction

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-GROUP-BY.asp

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-in-sql-server

In your specific case you’ll probably do fine if you just remove GROUP BY part because you’re not using any aggregate functions.